# Login Failed for User (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I have SQL Server 2008 running on my local machine. I have removed myself from Database --> Sercurity. Now I cannot login and I am getting following error

```
Login Failed for User (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)
```

My Login is auttenticating from Active Directory

Comment: And your AD user and/or Group is added in the Logins in SQL Server?

Comment: yes it was ... I was trying to do something and have removed it ...

Comment: Did you remove yourself from the dbms logins or from the database only? It might just be enough to specify "master" as default database in your connect options.

Comment: Then open ssms, extend the options and enter `master` or any other public database on the second tab, first input. Maybe you simply cannot log in because you cannot open your default database but your server credentials should still be intact.

Answer (score 0):

If you removed or disabled your `login` to the dmbs and have no other Logins to repair the situation, this [Tip from a Microsoft Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sqlman/archive/2011/06/14/tips-amp-tricks-you-have-lost-access-to-sql-server-now-what.aspx) may apply:

> Here are the steps you will need to perform:
>
> 1. Start the SQL Server instance using single user mode (or minimal configuration which will also put SQL Server in single user mode)
>
> From the command prompt type: SQLServr.Exe –m (or SQLServr.exe –f)
>
> Note: If the Binn folder is not in your environmental path, you’ll
>   need to navigate to the Binn folder.
>
> (Usually the Binn folder is located at: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn)
>
> 2. Once SQL Server service has been started in single user mode or with minimal configuration, you can now use the SQLCMD command from
>      command prompt to connect to SQL Server and perform the following
>      operations to add yourself back as an Admin on SQL Server instance.
>
> SQLCMD –S
>
> You will now be logged in to SQL Server as an Admin.
>
> 3. Once you are logged into the SQL Server using SQLCMD, issue the following commands to create a new account or add an existing login to
>      SYSADMIN server role.
>
> To create a new login and add that login to SYSADMIN server role:
>
> 1> CREATE LOGIN ‘’ with PASSWORD=’’
>
> 2> go
>
> 1> SP_ADDSRVROLEMEMBER '','SYSADMIN'
>
> 2>go
>
> To add an existing login to SYSADMIN server role, execute the
>   following:
>
> 1> SP_ADDSRVROLEMEMBER ‘’,’SYSADMIN’
>
> The above operation will take care of granting SYSADMIN privileges to
>   an existing login or to a new login.
>
> 4. Once the above steps are successfully performed, the next step is to stop and start SQL Server services using regular startup options.
>      (This time you will not need –f or –m)

Comment: This article describes how to do the same using GUI: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx